# Django admin date and time picker not working

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm following the 4 part tutorial at [djangoproject.com](http://djangoproject.com).

In the 2nd part of it (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/) im configuring the admin interface, it works fine, except for the fact that date and time javascript pickers does not appear.

I've been following the tutorial step by step, so I can't imagine what i'm doing wrong.

Also, the widget does not appear in admin/auth/user/1/ neither

Any ideas?
Thanks

**Update**

This is my code:

--models.py--

```
import datetime

from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

--admin.py--

```
from polls.models import Poll
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Poll)
```

Comment: You might have to show some code to get an answer. Ideally, you will have pared the problem down to a manageable size so that someone can grasp the problem easily.

Comment: Are you getting any 404 errors for the JS? Is the admin styled? I'm wondering if your admin media is even loading...

Comment: The admin is styled, but as Yuji says, i'm getting a 404 error on actions.min.js. Where it is supposed to be?

Comment: `django/contrib/admin/media/js/actions.min.js`

Comment: is javascript enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes, Javascript is enabled. I've reinstalled django, and it's working properly now. I guess that those files weren't created when I installed django the first time or something like that. Thanks to all of you who tried to help me with this issue :)

Comment: This is my first question here, what should i do? Delete it? Because its solved but i cant mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of django installation, i've reinstalled it and is now working properly.